# Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm learning php MVC and in my display model i got this fatal error 
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in `C:\xampp\htdocs\kowab\app\models\display.php` on line 36

line 36 is `$data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);`

Comment: That sounds like you're running a pretty big query.

Comment: The error message is fairly self explanatory, why it's happening is going to be guess work unless you provide more code (eg the query). 5 answers telling you to up the execution time limit but most queries shouldn't take that long unless it's a massive amount of data

Comment: Show the query, and an EXPLAIN of the query, and details of the keys in all tables being referenced

Answer (score 2):

To remove this error you have to increase `max_execution_time` in your `php.ini`. Afterwards you have to restart the apache.

Or you add `ini_set('max_execution_time', x)` at the top of your script.

But you should think about optimizing your query and code first.

Answer (score 2):

Are you watching from the Arabic man's tutorials? (Ali Hamdi)

I experienced the same thing and I made my else statement of the display class this way:

```
else
            {
                $num = mysql_num_rows($sql);
                while ($num > 0)
                    {
                        $data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
                        $num--;
                    }
            }

        return $data;
    }

}

?>
```

It didn't solve the problem, but it brought back the form at least. So I continued watching the rest of the tutorials and following him so that later I address that part. I have written him and awaiting for his response. as soon as he does, I'll get back to you with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Up your execution time by making your first line of code:

```
set_time_limit($x);
```

$x should be the maximum time in seconds for running the script.  A value of 0 will let the script run infinitely.

https://www.php.net/set_time_limit

**NOTE:** It is weird that you hit a 30 second time limit on line 36, so you probably have a problem with your code that we can't identify, because you haven't posted it.

Comment: I'm sure the problem with my code but i cant figure it my self, because am beginner here is my code:

Comment: <?php

// display

    class display extends awebarts {
 
 public function __construct($tablename) {
              
     
          $this->tablename= $tablename;
       
          $this->connectToDb();
    $this->getData();
    $this->close();
 }
 function getData() {  
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 1";
    
    if(!$sql = mysql_query($query))
    {
    throw new Exception (mysql_error());
    }
    else {
       $num= mysql_num_rows($sql);
    while($num >0)
    {
    $data= mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    }
    }
              return $data;
 }
 
 }

?>

Comment: the code in not clear here .. i will post it as an answer after 8 hours, thanks for your help

Comment: You're going to need to format it in something more legible.  How big is your database?

Answer (score 1):

```
set_time_limit($seconds);
```

Per [the docs](https://www.php.net/set_time_limit). If you pass a value of `0` for `$seconds` there will be no time limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase that time by looking for `max_execution_time` in **php.ini** but before that you need to know what cause this issue. Check your query there might be some loop or it returns a huge data

Answer (score 1):

here is my model

// display

```
class display extends awebarts {

public function __construct($tablename) {


         $this->tablename= $tablename;

         $this->connectToDb();

         $this->getData();

         $this->close();



}

function getData() {

   $query = "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 1";

   if(!$sql = mysql_query($query))
   {
   throw new Exception (mysql_error());
   }
   else {
      $num= mysql_num_rows($sql);
      while($num >0)
      {
      $data= mysql_fetch_array($sql);
      }
   }
          return $data;
}

}
```

?>``